# How to represent a Set or Dictionary in Chapel?

Tags: dictionary, chapel

In Python, it's easy to create a set of unique, un-ordered objects with

```
>>> s = set()
>>> s.add("table")
>>> s.add("chair")
>>> s.add("emu")
>>> s
set(['emu', 'table', 'chair'])
```

I know Chapel has domains, but is it proper to use these as sets? Are there any gotchas?  How about dictionaries?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Not all Chapel domains are sets, but 'associative domains' can be used as sets:

```
var s : domain(string);
s.add("table");
s.add("chair");
s.add("emu");
writeln(s); // {chair, table, emu}
var t = {"table", "chair", "emu"}; // associative domain literal
```

Like python sets, associative domains support membership checks and union, difference, intersection operations (among others). [See the online docs for more information.](https://chapel-lang.org/docs/latest/builtins/internal/ChapelArray.html#set-operations-on-associative-domains-and-arrays) By default associative domains are safe to use in parallel.

Chapel's 'associative arrays' are similar to python dictionaries. Chapel arrays are a mapping from indices to elements, so we can create an associative array with an associative domain:

```
var inds = {1, 2, 3, 7, 42};
var map : [inds] string;

map[3] = "foo";
map[42] = "bar";

inds.add(100); // add new index and element
assert(map[100] == "");
map[100] = "baz";

var lit = ["bob" => 1, "alice" => 2]; // assoc. array literal
```